# localstorage or cookie key name in client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, local-storage

I saw some code in github set localstorage key like 'user' in the localstorage. I think it should be at least $domain_name + 'user', because that might clash with other app. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each [origin](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) has it's own namespace. One origin does not have access to other origins' localStorage data.

Comment: oh ya, so my worry is not necessary ?

Comment: @JennyMok You don't have to worry about it. Please check out https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute

Answer (score 0):

The domain is not necessary be because the browser separates them by origin so different domains cannot the storage of another domain.

However, if you distribute a script or library that uses `localStorage` then you might want to prefix it with a namespace so it does not conflict with the `localStorage` of any other script that might run on the same domain.

Example if you have a media player plugin for jQuery your key could be "jquery.mediaplayer.color", or if you have a React component your key could be "react.mediaplayer.color".